# Is there any case in Greek mythology where humans swear on the river Styx?

Tags: greek

Mostly in Greek mythology, humans swear on Olympian gods such as Zeus while gods swear on the river Styx(Iliad 14.271).

**Then, is there any case where humans swear on the river Styx instead of Olympian gods?**
If not, why they didn't do that?
Considering that the gods adopt Styx as a witness, it would be more powerful oath when humans use Styx as a witness too.
Or is it impossible for humans to swear on the River Styx in Greek mythology?

Comment: Taking an oath by a god implied that god would punish you for taking his name in vain if you broke it.  For a god to swear by another god would require that god to have the power to punish you to be plausible.  As for swearing by himself. . . .

Comment: Thanks for the question. I had that same thought when I saw the other question bumped.

Comment: Note that the stated reason the Olympic gods swear on the Styx, is that the penalty for breaking such an oath is to be cut off from the rest of the gods for 9 years. That... doesn't really matter for mortals.